# How to I open a file when I start debugging in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I'm making a WinUI3 app in Visual Studio, and I'd like to open a file when I start debugging, so that `activatedEventArgs.Kind == ExtendedActivationKind.File` as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/migrate-to-windows-app-sdk/guides/applifecycle#file-type-association).

I'm really struggling to turn anything up with google, so am making a question here to help the next person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you already registered your file type (by following the steps in the link you provided) and your target app is already deployed (when run on VS),
you can debug it this way:

1. In VS, go to **Debug** > **Other Debug Targets** > **Debug Installed Debug Package...**
2. Select your app in **Installed App Packages**.
3. Select **Managed(.NET Core, .NET 5+)** in **Debug this code type**.
4. Check **Do not launch, but debug my code when it starts**.
5. Click **Start**. (The debugger starts running without launching your app.)
6. Double-click your target file. (Your app launches and the VS attaches the debugger to you app).